# Hadoop copy Local example to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am new in Hadoop and I am following some basic tutorials to get into it. 
One of the tutorial that I am following wants me to write an Hadoop MapReduce job in Python I have done everything successfully and these are the steps summarized:

1. Write a mapper.py and a reducer.py script
2. Copy local example data to hdfs
3. Run the MapReduce job

My question is: What if I have to modify my data frequently and then run the MapReduce job? Do I have every time to load the modified data on the hdfs or is there a way to modify directly on the hdfs?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload it to the HDFS every time you modify the data. The other option is to use HBASE which allows appending/updating the existing data.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't sound like a wise use of Hadoop. Hadoop is used where relatively static data is analyzed, i.e where you don't change your data. It basically works on **write once, read many** principle. A file once created, written, and closed need not be changed. And their is a strong reason behind this philosophy, which is **simplifying data coherency issues and enabling high throughput data access**.

Coming back to your actual question, yes you need to upload the data every time it changes. But why would you change your data so frequently? Just keep on storing the newer data into HDFS. Afterall Hadoop was meant to handle BIGdata.